# How correctly get resources from resource dictionary in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, refactoring, resourcedictionary

everyone, in WPF application I have the resource dictionary where is defined a lot of DataTemplates for controls and styles. For example

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PriceColumnCellTemplate">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Path=PriceQuotation, Mode=OneWay}"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="2,0"
        />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

in code behind class for View I have to get this data template. Now this is implementing in the following way

```
    private DataTemplate _priceColumnCellTemplate;
    private DataTemplate PriceColumnCellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_priceColumnCellTemplate == null)
                _priceColumnCellTemplate = (DataTemplate)_applicationResources["PriceColumnCellTemplate"];

            return _priceColumnCellTemplate;
        }
    }

    private DataTemplate _priceColumnCellEditingTemplate;
    private DataTemplate PriceColumnCellEditingTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_priceColumnCellEditingTemplate == null)
                _priceColumnCellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)_applicationResources["PriceColumnCellEditingTemplate"];

            return _priceColumnCellEditingTemplate;
        }
    }

    private DataTemplate _alternativePriceColumnCellTemplate;
    private DataTemplate AlternativePriceColumnCellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_alternativePriceColumnCellTemplate == null)
                _alternativePriceColumnCellTemplate = (DataTemplate)_applicationResources["AlternativePriceColumnCellTemplate"];

            return _alternativePriceColumnCellTemplate;
        }
    }
```

for each DataTemplate is created private field and the property for get value of this field.
In the same way is implementing for Styles.

The problem in this code is when I need to add a new DataTemplate I should add code like above for getting this DataTemplate form resources.

How to do refactor this code to avoid this duplication of code, and save the same functionality, may exist more flexible way to get resources from xaml file.

Please, help me with suggestion or give me an example how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need data templates to be maintained in the code behind? Are you referring them in XAMl again? If so please use `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` markup extensions... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer I need reference on this DataTemplates in code behind because, the data template of control should change dynamicaly depend on some conditions for example, in the DataGrid we have column, with Price, in some rows the pric should be readonly, and look like TextBock in others should be TextBox

Comment: Please see my answer below...

Comment: @Serghei - If this is WPF, why not just use data triggers to set the style?

Answer (score 1):

DataTemplates or any resources need not be held in the code behind view models. They can be dynamically supplied in case of [DataTemplateSelectors](http://mikestedman.blogspot.com/2009/04/datatemplateselector.html) which dynamically select the data template of any element to whome they apply ...

does this solve your issue better?

Comment: yes I know about Selectors, but I work with legacy code and I have a lot of code like I wrote above in question, in the same time this code is used to dynamicaly in code create DataGrid columns and apply DataTemplates, on this created colums. I don't have XAML at all for this columns.

Comment: Have you merged this resource dictionary to your App or Mainwindow? If so you could link them this way `Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["AlternativePriceColumnCellTemplate"] as DataTemplate`